# Adding TextView Programmatically in Fragment and setting to mainLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, textview

In my Fragment, instead of returning a view of my correspoding XML file, I am creating a layout and adding view to it as follows and then returning that layout:

```
LinearLayout firstLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
LinearLayout secondLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());

LinearLayout mainLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    mainLayout.addView(firstLinearLayout);
    mainLayout.addView(secondLinearLayout);

return(mainLayout);
```

Now, I've also tried to create a rootView to inflate my xml, and then access a TextView in that xml as follows:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xml_layout, container, false);

TextView check = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

and then add this `TextView` to my `mainLayout`:

```
mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
mainLayout.addView(firstLinearLayout);
mainLayout.addView(secondLinearLayout);
mainLayout.addView(check);
```

However, in the line assigning the `TextView` from my XML to `check`, I get a NullPointerException. I can't figure out why, can anyone help me out? Thank you.

Edit - Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/transparent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="here is random text"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:id="@+id/mphTextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you show error message?

Comment: @Sheychan yes, it is: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTextSize(float)' on a null object reference` This is of course, the line in which I try to change the text size right after `TextView check = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);` from my question above

Comment: do you have the correct id name.. check the Caps

Comment: post you xml code of xml_layout plz.

Comment: my guess is right, maybe he won't return haha

Comment: @jobcrazy I've added the XML code to the end of my question!

Answer (score 3):

You should be using

```
check = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mphTextView);
```

if the layout you have provided is the layout that you have inflated with rootView

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I've also tried to create a rootView to inflate my xml, and then access a TextView in that xml as

do not do that in that way, you will crash alot. your `TextView` already has a `Parent`, that is `rootView` and you are adding it to the `LinearLayout` -`mainLayout` ?? it doesn't crash? i think it is a disguised error information your child already has a parent

in your question you said

> However, in the line assigning the TextView from my XML to check, I get a NullPointerException.

but in the comments you said

> This is of course, the line in which I try to change the text size right after TextView check = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

so where do you crash actually?

Comment: When I try to assign`TextView "textView"` to `check`, it isn't actually assigned. So when it runs the next line: `check.setText`, it finds that `check` is null and crashes there.

Comment: its an xml problem your id for the textview is `mphTextView` and that is not the same as the one in your findviewbyid. check that, but after that you will get another error.  if that happens come back to this..  have a nice day@AreM

Answer (score 0):

mainLayout.addView(check); replace this with  mainLayout.addView(rootView);

Comment: thank you, but this is the method I'm avoiding because it ties the customization of the screen completely to the XML, and I need more flexibility. I've answered my own question however after figuring it out!

Answer (score 0):

I am using layouts in order to add more flexibility to my fragment - I can add and adjust layouts around the screen without having to rely on a static xml file.

So in my fragment java class, I added a new layout:

`LinearLayout mainLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());`

Then, I can add as many Views to this layout as I want. E.G.:

`mainLayout.addView(firstLinearLayout);
 mainLayout.addView(secondLinearLayout);`

Simply `return(mainLayout);` and your fragment will display this layout as the View.

You can create the "sub-Layouts" which were added to `mainLayout` programmatically and customize them. In order to add a text field in my fragment, I created an XML file with a `LinearLayout` containing a `TextView`. In order to add it to my `mainLayout`, I called it in the java class:

`LinearLayout addTextLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.random_text_layout);`

and then simply add this to `mainLayout` as done with the other layouts:

`mainLayout.addView(addTextLayout);`

By setting `LayoutBarParams`, you can adjust the positioning and scaling of these layouts to anywhere on screen. I also suspect that you can directly call a `TextView` rather than a layout from the XML but this works for me. I hope this helps you!